# ASP.NET MVC 3: Stack Overflow on a Html.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

By definition I had to post this question.  I received the error on this line using ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASPX form.  Where's my typo?

```
<a href="<%= Html.Action("About", "Home") %>">
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/images/newfront_04.jpg") %>" /></a>
```

[image: StackOverflowException]

I created a blank project to compare:

- Web Config is identical minus connection strings (including Views web.config)
- Global.asax.cs including routes is identical minus namespace
- Page directive is identical
- Home Controller code is identical minus namespace
- Taking this line out makes everything work
- The entire page is html with the exception of the page directive and ContentPlaceHolders
- This is the Site.Master file

Comment: Can you post the code for your route? Also the declaration for the Action and any Attributes over the controller. Just basically anything that is going into the logic for picking the route.

Comment: Is a partial view involved by any chance? You may want to include some more of view.

Comment: I see what you did there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Html.Action is actually rendering that action where you are putting that code, and it's causing reentrancy there. That is: it's calling the whole action and outputting the resulting view... not outputting the url.

What you probably wanted was Html.ActionLink (which renders the whole A tag for you), instead, or Url.Action, to just output the URL - rather than the action result again.

Comment: and again. and again. and again. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try Url.Action instead of Html.Action

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("About", "Home") %>">
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/images/newfront_04.jpg") %>" /></a>
```